# Remove an object class in Corona

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I have a new problem... I have a constuctor like this:

```
function Box.new(indexBox, item, imgClose, imgOpen) -- constructor
  local object = {
    indexBox = indexBox,
    item = item,
    imgClose = display.newImage( imgClose ),
    imgOpen = imgOpen
  }
  return setmetatable( object, Box_mt )
end
```

During the process I've created some `Box` objects and now I've finished to use them, so I want to remove this `Box` objects removing all the content of the object, included the image.
Are there any easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete ***all*** the box objects, you need some way to access all of them. The traditional and by far (IMHO) approach is to have a table storing references to the `Box` 'instances'. With such an approach all you would need is:

```
--BoxesTable contains all the boxes declared
for _,box in ipairs(BoxesTable) do
    box:removeSelf()
end
```